# onClick task not waiting for AlertDialog to show before running task

Tags: java, android

I'm having issues trying to get the alertdialog2 to show before running "runmods(activity);"

As soon as the button is pressed it doesn't show alertdialog2 and immediately runs "runmods"

What I want is to be able to press "execute", *then* alertdialog2 shows, *then* runmods run.

```
public static void execute(final MainActivity activity) {
    Rooted.rooted(activity);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
    final AlertDialog alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to execute and reboot?");
    alertDialog2.setTitle("Executing");
    alertDialog2.setMessage("Your phone will now reboot");

    alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            alertDialog2.setOnShowListener(new AlertDialog.OnShowListener() {
                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

                    runmods(activity);
                }
            });
            alertDialog2.show();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is calling `runmods(activity)` in a new `Runnable` which is run after a delay. That is, in the `onShow` method of `alertDialog2`, use the following code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runmods(activity);
    }
}, 4000); //alertDialog2 will be displayed for 4 seconds before runmods is called
```

So the complete modified code would be:

```
public static final int DIALOG2_DELAY_SECS = 4;

public static void execute(final MainActivity activity) {
    Rooted.rooted(activity);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog2.setTitle("Executing");
    alertDialog2.setMessage("Your phone will now reboot");
    alertDialog2.setOnShowListener(new AlertDialog.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runmods(activity);
                }
            }, DIALOG2_DELAY_SECS*1000);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to execute and reboot?");
    alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            alertDialog2.show();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want alert 2 to be shown for like 3 seconds, try to use thread and make it sleep 3000ms before starting runmods